# Converting Ranges

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am writing a program for the arduino that takes a number as input and displays colors based on that input.  At any given time, I know the value of the variables *min* and *max* where *min* is the minimum value of the input range and *max* is the maximum value of the input range.  The problem is, in order for my program to work I have to convert this range to a range of 0-80.  Is there a mathematical equation I can use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote min and max by $m$ and $M$ and use

$$f(x) = 80\cdot \frac{x-m}{M-m}$$

Then, $f$ proportionally maps the interval $[m,M]$ to $[0,80]$ as you asked. (In other words, as $x$ moves from $m$ to $M$, if it covered $a\%$ of the interval $[m,M]$, the result, $f(x)$ will have covered $a\%$ of the resulting interval $[0,80]$.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.